# GWT detect GAE version changes and reload

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

My users use my GWT app for an average of 40 minutes at a time, so when I upgrade the version number of the GAE backend, there's a long period of time when the version they're running in their browser doesn't match the version supporting it on the server.

Most functionality is broken, throwing IncompatibleRemoteServiceExceptions.  How can I detect these on the client end?  I don't see a way to get an error code out of the onFailure method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you receive an `IncompatibleRemoteServiceException` in `onFailure()` you need to prompt the user to reload the page. Spawn a [DialogBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DialogBox.html) (modal & with glass) informing the user that the application is out of date and a button that, when clicked, calls [`Window.Location.reload()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html#reload%28%29)

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I missed the `Throwable` parameter to `onFailure`.  Thanks for the pointer.