# under what circumstances (if any) can I continue to run "out of date" GWT clients when I update my GAEJ version?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

following on from this question:
[GWT detect GAE version changes and reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788266/gwt-detect-gae-version-changes-and-reload)

I would like to further clarify some things.

I have an enterprise app (GWT 2.4 & GAEJ 1.6.4 - using GWT-RPC) that my users typically run all day in their browsers, indeed some don't bother refreshing the browser from day to day.   I  make new releases on a pretty regular basis, so am trying to streamline the process for minimal impact to my users. - Not all releases concern all users, so I'd like to minimize the number of restarts.

I was hoping it might be possible to do the following.  Categorize my releases as follows:
1) releases that will cause an IncompatibleRemoteServiceException to be thrown
and 2) those that don't : i.e. only affect the server, or client but not the RPC interface.

Then I could make lots of changes to the client and server without affecting the interface between the two.  As long as I don't make a modification to the RPC interface, presumably I can change server code and or client code and the exception won't be thrown?  Right? or will any redeployment of GAE cause an old client to get an IncompatibleRemoteServiceException ?

If I was able to do that I could batch up interface busting changes into fairly infrequent releases and notify my users a restart will be required.

many thanks for any help.

Comment: This was one big reason I got rid of GWT-RPC altogether.  With a simple JSON-based api to the server you can easily understand when an API change has been made, and even provide backwards-compatible support.  You lose some of the nice coupling and code generation of GWT-RPC, but with a shared DTO class and something like RESTEasy it's not too cumbersome.  Plus you get a public API practically for free!

Comment: thanks for comments Riley.  Bit late for me to change my messaging mechanism though.  See results of what I've found in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I needed an answer pretty quick so I thought I'd just do some good old fashioned testing to see what's possible. Hopefully this will be useful for others with production systems using GWT-RPC.

Goal is to be able to release updates / fixes without requiring all connected browsers to refresh.  Turns out there is quite a lot you can do.

So, after my testing, here's what you can and can't do:

**no problem**

1. add a new call to a RemoteService
2. just update some code on the server e.g. simple bug fix, redeploy
3. just update some client (GWT) code and redeploy (of course anyone wanting new client functionality will have to refresh browser, but others are unaffected)

**limited problems**

1. add a parameter to an existing RemoteService method - this one is interesting, that particular call will throw "IncompatibleRemoteServiceException" (of course) but all others calls to the **same** Remote Service or other Remote Services (Impl's) are unaffected.
2. Add a new type (as a parameter) to any method within a RemoteService - this is the most interesting one, and is what led me to do this testing.  It will render that **whole RemoteService out of date** for existing clients with IncompatibleRemoteServiceException.  However you can still use other RemoteServices. - I need to do some more testing here to fully understand or perhaps someone else knows more?

so if you know what you're doing you can do quite a lot without having to bother your users with refreshes or release announcements.

Comment: unfortunately I just tried to do 3. "just update some client code".  And it failed this time! So back to the drawing board.  I would really like to know if anyone has the definitive answer here as to what can and can't be done regarding backward compatibility of GWT-RPC interfaces.